# Binding multiple values to one field on form

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have 6 input boxes  - each for 4 digits. After entering 4 digits, automatically the cursor should go to the next input box. All are mandatory.

Now setting auto focus to next text box can be done on 'onChange' event.
But how do I bind value of these 6 input boxes to one field on my form.
Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSP, you need 6 input fields as below,

```
<form:input path="categoriesList[0].name" id="categoriesList[0].name" size="4"/>
<form:input path="categoriesList[1].name" id="categoriesList[1].name" size="4"/>
```

and so on..

In your Form, you need to declare categoriesList as ArrayList or Array and need setters and getters for that field

Comment: Thank you Java P. I implemented it in same way as you said.. Its working :)